# How to remove `js/responsive.js` and `js/theme.js` from Magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="Magento_Theme::js/responsive.js " />
    <remove src="Magento_Theme::js/theme.js " />
</head>
</page>
```

I've tried the above but no luck. Also tried removing "Magento_Theme::" portion as well and it doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Create in the same path: [my theme]/web/js/_responsive.js with minimum file content:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'mage/tabs',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';
});
```

Or this:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They are defined in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

I highly advice against editing core Magento files, but so far it's not possible to overwrite this with your own requirejs-config as of 2.1.1, even if it says so in [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take the file from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

Copy it to the root of your theme folder

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/requirejs-config.js
```

Remove the reference to the two files (under deps)